# Strong convexity of the trace of the square root of a matrix function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Any clues about how to prove that the following function is strongly-concave in $x$? (We conjecture it is $2$-strongly concave but cannot prove it. We have already proved strict concavity through using the fact that $x^2$ is operator (strictly) concave). 
$$
  f(x): S^n \rightarrow R, \ x \mapsto {\rm tr}\left(\sqrt{{\rm Diag}(x) - x x^T}\right),
$$
where $x$ is a column vector in the unit simplex. i.e., 
$x \geq 0$, $\sum_jx_j = 1$, $\sqrt{}$ is the matrix square root function,
and ${\rm Diag(x)}$ is a diagonal matrix which stores entries of $x$ on its diagonal.

Thanks in advance.